# How to set and inject property Value from Test in Junit

Tags: spring, junit

My Service class uses a property set it application.properties

```
@Service
public class Service {
    @Value("${my.prop}")
    private String prop;        
    public Response doWork(String param1,String param2){
       System.out.println(prop);    //NULL!!! 
    }   
}
```

I want to test it and set my own value:

Test Class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "application.properties",properties = { "my.prop=boo" })
public class ServiceUnitTest {   
    @InjectMocks
    private Service service;    

    @Test
    public void fooTest(){      
        Response re = service.doWork("boo", "foo");
    }
}
```

But when I run the test, the value is null (not even the value that exists in application.properties).

Comment: Use constructor injection rather than field injection. Then use `new Service("whatever")` to create your service instance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with MockitoJUnitRunner, but I am able to achieve this using PowerMockRunner.

Set up the application context with a test configuration, and autowire the bean from you application context into your test class. You also shouldn't need the "locations = " bit in the @TestPropertySource annotation.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "my.prop=boo" })
public class ServiceUnitTest {   

    @TestConfiguration
    static class ServiceUnitTestConfig {
        @Bean
        public Service service() {
            return new Service();
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    Service service;

    @Test
    public void fooTest(){      
        Response re = service.doWork("boo", "foo");
    }
}
```